# Saving Array easy way

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have used NSuserDefaults and NSkeyedArchive before but i dont think it will work for my new project..

I get data back from JSON and store it in an array (name,age,country) (all NSString)

i want to make a save button in the detail view so that it saves that person's data.

And show the saved data in another tableview. (for loop on the array and get all objects back)

How should i handle this in a easy way.. i except max 40 stored names so its not so heavy..

So in short i want a function like you see in "home app's" where you can "favorite/store a house"

-- Update

viewDidLoad

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Names.plist"];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

arrayWithNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arrayWithNames addObjectsFromArray:array];
```

Savebutton

```
NSMutableArray *nameInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.name,self.age,self.country, nil];

[arrayWithNames addObjectsFromArray:nameInfo];



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Names.plist"];


[arrayWithNames writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

This works but i get all data together instead of every array as an independent object

btw i made sure there cant be a NULL :)

Comment: Check out `NSCoding`.

Comment: Use `[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` or store the array in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @rmaddy but if i use that, i overwrite the file every time..

Comment: Yes it will. If the new array has the complete list (which is should) then that is fine. You said yourself it's a small list. This would be fine with hundreds of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all of the data is `NSString` values, as you say, you can just use `writeToFile:atomically:` to save an array to a file. *However*, JSON sometimes contains nulls, which aren't compatible with that method. If you try to use that method when nulls are present, it will throw an exception. If there's any chance of nulls (and there almost always is a chance), you'll need to take some precautions. A couple of possibilities:

- Make mutable copies of your data, run through it, and remove nulls or replace them with something else (like an empty string).
- Convert the data back to JSON via `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]` and then write the resulting `NSData` to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I not quite understand your question.

But in your case what I did was create a **Model** with the structure of information I intended to store (in your case looked **Person**) and created an array in which i will add the objects **Person**

Could use several cases to save, but in my opinion, the simplest would be through the NSUserDefaults (the solution depends heavily on your database).

Soo, you will have the model **Person**

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
@interface Person : NSObject


@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *country;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *age;
...
```

With the methods for the encryption:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.age forKey:@"age"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.country forKey:@"country"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name "];
        self.age = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"age"];
        self.country = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"country"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you create a NSMutableArray where you add your objects.

```
[arrayPeople addObject:person];
```

When you decide to store in your application data you can do this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSData *myEncodedObjectShopping = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayPeople];
[defaults setObject:myEncodedObjectShopping forKey:@"people"];
```

To retrive the data:

```
NSData *myDecodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"people"];
NSMutableArray *decodedArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myDecodedObject];
```